# How can i keep several p tags on the same line/

Tags: html, css

How do I use several p tags in my code and keep them all on the same line on the website?

Here's my code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <title>Katy's Geck-Tacular Geckos</title>
    <div class="diva">
<h1>Katy's Geck-Tacular Geckos!</h1>
        <p>Hello</p><p>customer</p><p>welcome!</p>
        
        </div>
    </head>
<body>
    
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by same line. Please be clear what exactly do you want?

Comment: on the website i want all the p tags to be left to right on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap all `p` in a container and add `display: flex`. It will place all `p` tag `left` to `right`. But you need to add some space between them with `gap: .5rem`;

Add space as per your requirements.

**TIP:** `p` tags are not for this purpose, they are meant to be come in new line, You should use `span` instead. They are by default `inline`

```css
.p-container{
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="diva">
  <h1>Katy's Geck-Tacular Geckos!</h1>
  <div class="p-container">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>customer</p>
    <p>welcome!</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

It would be better to use `span` instead `p` and wrap all spans under any `block-level` element e.g `p`, `div` etc.

```html
<div class="diva">
  <h1>Katy's Geck-Tacular Geckos!</h1>
  <div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>customer</span>
    <span>welcome!</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you want

Comment: Yes that's what I want,

Comment: I will, but overflow says I have to wait 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

p tags are meant to be paragraphs. So each p tag will start a new line. Maybe you can use the span tag to keep the content in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

For the example provided - you need a single p element with spans inside - and since spans are inline elements - they will sit beside each other. Useing p elements and flex to adjust styling is a little bit of using the wrong tool for the job, imo.

You can style the spans, space them out or color them differently - but smeatically - they are all fragments of the single p element - and the right html element for that is the span).

```html
<div>
  <h1>Katy's Geck-Tacular Geckos!</h1>
  <p>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>customer</span>
    <span>welcome!</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

first solution : put all the paragraphs in a div and put display flex on the div but it is not recommended

```html
 <div class="container">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>customer</p>
    <p>welcome!</p>
  </div>
```

```css
.container{
 display : "flex";
}
```

second solution : use spans instead of paragraphs and it will automatically be in a same line

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
```